# Adding a dynamic image to a PDF using ColdFusion and iText

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, itext

I pieced together some code to insert a dynamic image into a PDF using both [ColdFusion](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/) and [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/), while filling in some form fields as well. After I got it working and blogged about it, I couldn't help but think that there might be a better way to accomplish this. I'm using the basic idea of this in a production app right now so any comments or suggestion would be most welcomed.

```
<cfscript>
// full path to PDF you want to add image to
readPDF = expandpath(”your.pdf”);
// full path to the PDF we will output. Using creatUUID() to create
// a unique file name so we can delete it afterwards
writePDF = expandpath(”#createUUID()#.pdf”);
// full path to the image you want to add
yourimage = expandpath(”dynamic_image.jpg”);

// JAVA STUFF!!!
// output buffer to write PDF
fileIO = createObject(”java”,”java.io.FileOutputStream”).init(writePDF);
// reader to read our PDF
reader = createObject(”java”,”com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader”).init(readPDF);
// stamper so we can modify our existing PDF
stamper = createObject(”java”,”com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper”).init(reader, fileIO);
// get the content of our existing PDF
content = stamper.getOverContent(reader.getNumberOfPages());
// create an image object so we can add our dynamic image to our PDF
image = createobject(”java”, “com.lowagie.text.Image”);
// get the form fields
pdfForm = stamper.getAcroFields();
// setting a value to our form field
pdfForm.setField(”our_field”, “whatever you want to put here”);
// initalize our image
img = image.getInstance(yourimage);
// centering our image top center of our existing PDF with a little margin from the top
x = (reader.getPageSize(1).width() - img.scaledWidth()) - 50;
y = (reader.getPageSize(1).height() - img.scaledHeight()) / 2 ;
// now we assign the position to our image
img.setAbsolutePosition(javacast(”float”, y),javacast(”float”, x));
// add our image to the existing PDF
content.addImage(img);
// flattern our form so our values show
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
// close the stamper and output our new PDF
stamper.close();
// close the reader
reader.close();
</cfscript>
<!— write out new PDF to the browser —>
<cfcontent type=”application/pdf” file = “#writePDF#” deleteFile = “yes”>
```

Comment: CF8 makes this ridiculously easy.  (Still cool example though! :) )

Comment: i'm not using a watermark as just inserting an image into an existing PDF.

Comment: @rip747 I just wanted to say that if you need watermark, there's simple way to do it with cfpdf tag. As for inserting image into text bod using cfpdf+ddx, it seems too complex to do (at least with my knowledge). Your way is simpler.

Comment: Yes, in _some_ cases using cfpdf watermark is simpler. It should be the same as writing on the over content. But it is a little buggy. So if you have problems, this is a good alternative. BTW: You could also stream the output directly (moderate sized files). Use a ByteArrayOutputStream in place of FileOutputStream. Then use <cfcontent type="application/pdf" variable="#fileIO.toByteArray()#"> to serve the file.  It is probably not a bad practice to close fileIO explicitly at the end (especially in any error handling). I have occaisionally had issues with locked files when I did not do that.

Answer (score 2):

`<cfpdf>` + DDX seems possible.

[See http://forums.adobe.com/thread/332697](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/332697)

Comment: The above link requires an Adobe account as well as special authorization in order to view.

Answer (score 0):

I have made it in another way with itext library
I don´t want overwrite my existing pdf with the image to insert, so just modify the original pdf inserting the image, just insert with itext doesn´t work for me.

So, I have to insert the image into a blank pdf (http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=59)
And then join my original pdf and the new pdf-image. Obtaining one pdf with several pages.
(http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=110)

After that you can overlay the pdf pages with this cool concept
http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=113

Comment: I'm now improving the way to do this, more directly, without overlaying all the pdf pages, just overlaying what I need; with **addtemplate of PdfContentByte** from itext