# Examples of filling pdf form with iText in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, itext

Looking for some examples of iText 5 and ColdFusion 7.

I need to fill some pdf forms with data from the DB all the iText and ColdFusion examples I found are at least 4 years old and use previous version of iText.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have an example on how to do this in one of my previous question:

[Adding a dynamic image to a PDF using ColdFusion and iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697122/adding-a-dynamic-image-to-a-pdf-using-coldfusion-and-itext)

Comment: Thanks rip... this worked like a charm, only thing I changed was the package name to match the iText 5.0 changes... com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader