# How to Add a link to a PDF with ColdFusion and iText

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, hyperlink, itext

I used this technique to insert an image

[Adding a dynamic image to a PDF using ColdFusion and iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697122/adding-a-dynamic-image-to-a-pdf-using-coldfusion-and-itext)

Now, I need to insert a link to a external URL at `X/Y` and text inside with itext and ColdFusion.

Can someone help me do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "text". The text of the link, or something else ..?

Comment: Just curious, but did you try using cfpdf action="addWatermark" to add the image? Since you are writing on the overContent anyway, it is essentially the same thing. It seems to support all the needed properties: opacity, pages, foreground and position. Worth a shot anyway..

Comment: I have some difference whis cfpdf, The first is the alpha transparency of the PNG, for this application I dont need Opacity or forground.
I have only one probleme whis 'image size', but i have the shame probleme whis cfpdf.

Comment: You mean you are having problems with both iText and cfpdf? Feel free to post another question, and maybe we can come up with some ideas. Also, what version of CF are you using .. 8 or 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is rough example that works with CF9. There are probably more elegant methods, but this should give you the basic idea.

Note - IIRC CF8 uses an earlier version of iText (1.4). CF9 uses 2.1.0. So I am relatively certain it will not run "as is" with CF8. If needed, you can use the JavaLoader.cfc to run a later version.

**Update:** Modified to show one way of defining a specific font, size and color. The correct settings will vary depending on your system, desired font, encoding, etcetera.

```
<cfscript>
     inputPath = "c:\sourceFile.pdf";
     outputPath = "c:\sourceFileWithLink.pdf";

     try {
        // initialize objects
        pdfReader = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader").init( inputPath );
        outStream = createObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream").init( outputPath );
        pdfStamper = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper").init( pdfReader, outStream );

        // create a chunk with a link to www.google.com
        chunk = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.Chunk").init("Go To Google");
        chunk.setAnchor("http://www.google.com");

        //////////////////////////////////////////
        // Define embedded font 
        BaseFont = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont");
        Font = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.Font");
        bf = BaseFont.createFont("c:/windows/fonts/Framd.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

        // Create the main font object (size 14)
        Color = createObject("java", "java.awt.Color");
        textFont = Font.init(bf, 14, Font.UNDERLINE, Color.RED);   
        // Apply the font to the chunk text
        chunk.setFont( textFont );
        //////////////////////////////////////////

        // prepare to write the link onto the *first* page only        
        cb = pdfStamper.getOverContent(1); // first page
        ct = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText").init(cb);
        ct.addElement( chunk );

        // position towards bottom right of page
        page = pdfReader.getPageSize(1);
        llx =  page.getRight()-200;   
        lly = page.getBottom();       
        urx = page.getRight();                
        ury = page.getBottom() + 36;     
        // initialize column dimensions
        ct.setSimpleColumn(llx, lly, urx, ury);
        // write the text
        ct.go();

        WriteOutput("Finished!");
    }        
    finally 
    {
        // cleanup
        if (IsDefined("pdfStamper")) {
            pdfStamper.close();
        }
        if (IsDefined("outStream")) {
            outStream.close();
        }
    } 
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Hooo ..
marvelous .. thats work !!
Could you explain me how to change font, size, color and unlerline ?
for text ?

Comment: Create a Font object and apply it to the Chunk holding the text. You will probably need to create a BaseFont and java.awt.Color object first. Then use them to create a Font() with the desired size, style and Color. http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/Font.html

Comment: Oops, that is the wrong version of the API (5.0.0). This one looks closer
http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/lowagie/text/Font.html

Comment: thanks .. but i have realy a probleme for translate Java in coldfusion :S

Comment: @Alain - I updated the example with a font. You may want to study it first. See what it is doing. It is never a good idea to use code you do not understand ;)

Comment: Tanks,you are true ...
This is my first time whis iText, I will strudy that, realy poverfull for PDF.
This is my first time here , I need to .. close question ? hors somthings ?

Comment: Yes, if it answers your question you should close it by accepting it as the answer.