# Exception occurred while instantiating a Java object (ColdFusion)

Tags: java, coldfusion, itext

I found this solution for [adding a link to a pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226993/how-to-adding-link-in-to-a-pdf-whis-coldfusion-and-itext) some time ago. It works like a charm, if used occasionally (ea reboot the server between each use). I've found out that for some reason (I'm not very experienced with java and iText) when trying to run this script a second time (without reboot), ColdFusion returns the error :

> Object instantiation exception.
>
> An exception occurred while instantiating a Java object. The class
>   must not be an interface or an abstract class. Error: ''.

ColdFusion then indicates that the line causing the error seems to be at :

```
pdfReader = createObject("java","com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader").init(inputPath);
```

Who knows more about this, has a solution or can explain why this happens? I think that somehow the java object created 'survives' inside java but off course doesn't survive inside CF.

Stack trace :

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.CreateObject(JavaProxy.java:166)
    at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.invoke(JavaProxy.java:80)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2360)
    at cfSched_PushJobs2MultiPress32ecfm1907554548._factor16(E:\Inetpub\DashBoards\MultiPress\Sched_PushJobs2MultiPress3.cfm:549)
    at cfSched_PushJobs2MultiPress32ecfm1907554548._factor17(E:\Inetpub\DashBoards\MultiPress\Sched_PushJobs2MultiPress3.cfm:547)
    at cfSched_PushJobs2MultiPress32ecfm1907554548._factor45(E:\Inetpub\DashBoards\MultiPress\Sched_PushJobs2MultiPress3.cfm:543)
    at cfSched_PushJobs2MultiPress32ecfm1907554548._factor25(E:\Inetpub\DashBoards\MultiPress\Sched_PushJobs2MultiPress3.cfm)
    at cfSched_PushJobs2MultiPress32ecfm1907554548._factor49(E:\Inetpub\DashBoards\MultiPress\Sched_PushJobs2MultiPress3.cfm:512)
    at cfSched_PushJobs2MultiPress32ecfm1907554548._factor51(E:\Inetpub\DashBoards\MultiPress\Sched_PushJobs2MultiPress3.cfm:509)
    at cfSched_PushJobs2MultiPress32ecfm1907554548._factor53(E:\Inetpub\DashBoards\MultiPress\Sched_PushJobs2MultiPress3.cfm:461)
    at cfSched_PushJobs2MultiPress32ecfm1907554548._factor58(E:\Inetpub\DashBoards\MultiPress\Sched_PushJobs2MultiPress3.cfm:213)
    at cfSched_PushJobs2MultiPress32ecfm1907554548._factor129(E:\Inetpub\DashBoards\MultiPress\Sched_PushJobs2MultiPress3.cfm:207)
    at cfSched_PushJobs2MultiPress32ecfm1907554548._factor146(E:\Inetpub\DashBoards\MultiPress\Sched_PushJobs2MultiPress3.cfm:102)
    at cfSched_PushJobs2MultiPress32ecfm1907554548.runPage(E:\Inetpub\DashBoards\MultiPress\Sched_PushJobs2MultiPress3.cfm:1)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:360)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:79)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map failed
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:758)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.MappedRandomAccessFile.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.MappedRandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PRTokeniser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:755)
    ... 55 more
```

Comment: With java objects, the actual cause of the error is contained in the [stack trace](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d24.html). Please update your question with the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a huge file, but a lot depends on how much server memory is available and how much is being used by other processes. You might want to try using a [`RandomAccessFileOrArray`](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/javadoc/itext-2.1.7/com/lowagie/text/pdf/RandomAccessFileOrArray.html#RandomAccessFileOrArray%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) for the reader and also buffer the writer output. See if that helps. Also, be sure you are closing the stamper and output stream.

```
// use random access when reading 
raf = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray").init(inputPath, false, true);
pdfReader = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader").init( raf, javacast("null", ""));
... 
// buffer the output
fos = createObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream");
outStream = createObject("java", "java.io.BufferedOutputStream").init( fos.init( outputPath ) );
pdfStamper = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper").init( pdfReader, outStream );
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured there would be enough memory available, but your improvement might just do it. Will try this right away!

Comment: Ultimately you may still need to increase memory. But trying RandomAccessFileOrArray(..plainRandomAccess) first cannot hurt.

Comment: Thanks, the solution you suggested with RandomAccessFileOrArray works fine!  I'll also check into the memory issue.

Comment: (For the archives) Apparently the original error means you [do not have enough _contiguous_ memory](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/READ-LARGE-FILE-1-5gb-Error-tp3068682p3069808.html) available. So the fallback is to try `plainRandomAccess`, which unlike nio, must not require *contiguous* memory.

Comment: The code runs on a VMware virtualized server together with some 7 or 8 other instances. While there's plenty of ram and cpu power available, I'll do a little digging to find out if this might be a reason for the allocated memory to be fragmented in any way and thus causing this error...

Answer (score 1):

The error gives the problem. Go down to the first "Caused by" line:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed     at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
```

The root cause is that you ran out of memory. Try increasing the available memory to your JVM.

Comment: It's a 600 pages, non-optimized 86MB pdf file. Since it works fine the first time and doesn't work afterwards, even after restarting the ColdFusion service, I figured I could exclude the memory issue.
I'll run an optimization, which divides the file size by two, before running the above code.

Comment: Thank you, I will check the JVM setting in the CF admin.