# Sizing image problem in PDF whis iText or cfPDF in Coldfusion 8

Tags: image, pdf, coldfusion, itext, cfpdf

WHen I insert a Image into a existing PDF whis CFPDF or directely whis iText, the size of my image is increased by 1.5.

How to control the image size?

my code are inspired from:
[Adding a dynamic image to a PDF using ColdFusion and iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697122/adding-a-dynamic-image-to-a-pdf-using-coldfusion-and-itext)

Comment: That example is not scaling. Can you post your code?

Comment: Huu ... finaly, no error of scaling.... sorry for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing a catalogue type PDF it will be best to ensure your images are manually sized in the cfml to a certain height and width.

I have printed tons of images in Coldfusion into a pdf before and come across a few things, you might have one of the following:

1) Image resolution is higher than screen.  I had a case, a while ago that the image was set to 300 dpi and the document wasn't.  It was with a third party PDF creator however.

2) You might want to check the resolution of the pdf you're printing to (whether it's screen (72 dpi) vs. print (150+ dpi)) and see if there's something there.

3) If you can, size the images manually to have a maximum

Comment: tanks to you for this response