# How can I get ColdFusion to scale images of any type?

Tags: image-processing, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

**Server Config:**

- *Windows Server 2003*
- *IIS 6*
- *ColdFusion 8 Standard Edition*
- *Java Version 6 Update 18*

I have a ColdFusion application that allows users to upload images that will be added to an existing PDF. When the images are added to the PDF, they have to fit within a minimum/maximum height and width, so the uploaded image needs to be scaled to fit.

For instance, let's say the minimum height and width for a given image is 100x100, and the maximum height and width is 200x200, and the user uploads an image that is 500x1000. I use the logic below to scale that image down without skewing the image (it keeps its original shape) to 100x200. For an image smaller than the minimum, it is scaled up (in the example above, a 50x50 image would be scaled up to 100x100).

Unfortunately, I'm running into a lot of problems with users uploading "invalid images". I know that ColdFusion has problems working with Progressive JPEGs and CMYK JPEGs, but even some TIFFs are throwing errors. Also, a 3MB TIFF image takes over a minute to scale (not to mention the loss of resolution that occurs, which I have submitted as a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9198561/31298).)

I've added logic to prevent ColdFusion from trying to process an "invalid image" by using the `IsImageFile()` function, but the users are very frustrated when they have an image that they can open and view on their PC, but we can't accept it. Do online print companies (i.e. Shutterfly, Kodak, etc.) have these issues? I can't remember ever having an issue on these websites (though I know they may not necessarily use ColdFusion).

Any thoughts on what I can do to allow more types of images to be used (Progressive, CMYK, etc.) and improve performance?

Comment: imagemagick.org over cfimage for reliability and speed

Answer (score 3):

You will likely have to use a non-CF solution like we had to do before CF8. Some libraries mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158756/what-is-the-best-image-manipulation-library

Scaling time is heavily dependent on the algorithm you chose to use. Adding images to PDFs in ColdFusion is unpredictable at best. I found them to be often inflated, dramatically increasing the PDF file size.

Here is some information from the docs:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_in-k_16.html

Supported image file formats

The cfimage tag operates on a number of different file formats. To list the formats that are supported on the server where the ColdFusion application is deployed, use the GetReadableImageFormats function and the GetWriteableImageFormats function.

ColdFusion supports the following default image formats on Macintosh, Windows, and Unix operating systems:

**JPEG**

**GIF**

**TIFF**

**PNG**

**BMP**

ColdFusion does not support the following image formats:

**Animated GIF**

**Multipage TIFF**

**PSD**

**AI**

***CMYK support***

The cfimage tag supports reading and writing CMYK images, but does not support actions that require converting the images. For example, you can use CMYK images with the read, write, writeToBrowser, resize, rotate, and info actions. You cannot use CMYK images with the convert, captcha, and border actions. The same rule applies to image functions. For example, the ImageNew, ImageRead, and ImageWrite functions support CMYK images, but the ImageAddBorder function does not.